# Is this shorthand notation correct for the partial derivatives in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I just have a quick question about partial derivatives/mathematical relations in thermodynamics. Is the following statement correct?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\left [ \left ( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right )_{v} \right ]_{T}=\left ( \frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial v\partial T} \right )_{v,T}$$

Comment: Just realized that this is literally redundant notation. There is no reason to write T and v outside the parentheses.

Comment: Are you still seeking an answer? You can either post an answer if you have one or else delete the question if you no longer see value in it.

Answer (score 1):

The independent variables are already given by T and v in
$$\frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial v\partial T}$$
so the notation $$\left ( \frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial v\partial T} \right )_{v,T}$$

is redundant.